# How to add filename to end of every line - all files in all subdirectories

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I want to add a line to my bash script (ubuntu 16) to add the filename to the end of every line in a file - that is every file in a folder and all files in all subfolders.

Filenames are alphanumeric with some special characters like -_.

For example:

Line in file `filename_ghrut.txt` before:

```
blah blah blah
blahblah blahblah
```

Line in file `filename_ghrut.txt` after:

```
blah blah blah filename_ghrut.txt
blahblah blahblah filename_ghrut.txt
```

I have searched around but most commands don't seem to work.

I want to run this on all files in all subfolders of a specific directory.

Big thanks.

I found this, but it doesn't quite work:

```
ls file{1..5}.txt|xargs -I% sed -i 's/$/;%/' %
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl` and `find`

```
find . -type f -exec perl -i -pe 's/$/ $ARGV/' {} +
```

- `s/$/ $ARGV/` add space and filename to end of each line
- `-i` for inplace editing, use `i.bkp` if you want to retain a backup of original files
- If your `find` doesn't support `+`, use `\;` instead
- `find . -type f` will give list of all files in current directory
- `-exec` allows to use a command to act upon all those files
- Use `find . -type f -name '*.txt'` if you want to restrict to only files ending with `.txt`

Thanks @thiagowfx for pointing that above solution will add filename as `./file.txt`, `./foo/file2.txt`, etc

Use this to add only filename without any `./` etc

```
find . -type f -exec perl -i -pe 's/$/$ARGV=~s|.*\/| |r/e' {} +
```

- `$ARGV=~s|.*\/| |r` will give filename with all characters upto `/` removed

Comment: Nice solution too! I would advise to use `execdir` instead of `exec`; this way, you get the basename of each file. For example, `a.txt` instead of `./dir/a.txt`.

Comment: @thiagowfx thanks for pointing that out, will edit :)

Comment: Sundeep - perl command works fine - but it adds the list of subfolders and filename  e.g.  blahblah  /folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/filename.txt   Any way to just add the filename without the directories?

Comment: @speld_rwong check edit

Comment: Sundeep  -- just added -i inplace and it works  -  THANKS  >>>>  find . -type f -exec perl -i -pe 's/$/$ARGV=~s|.*\/| |r/e' {} +

Comment: @speld_rwong yeah, forgot to add that as I was testing it out... :D

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -type f -exec gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '
  BEGINFILE {suffix = FILENAME; sub(/.*\//, "", suffix)}
  {print $0, suffix}' {} +
```

Beware that if there are several hard links of the same file, the name for each will be added (in no particular order) to each line of that file.

In any case, **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`

Answer (score -1):

Try this, using `find` and `sed`:

```
find /path/to/top_directory -type f -execdir sed -i -e "s/$/ {}/" {} \;
```

Replace `/path/to/top_directory` with the directory where the files you want to edit are.

Comment: thiagowfx  - I get this error with >>>>>>  sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'

Comment: What version of `sed` are you using? Is it GNU sed or BSD sed? It works with the default `sed` on my system (MacOS 10.12.4).

Comment: @thiagowfx, GNU find passes the filename as `./file.name` even with `-execdir` so the slash there clashes with the slash used as separator for the sed command. You'd need to use something like `s%$% {}%` with a character any of the filenames don't contain.

Comment: Great find! That's probably the reason why OP couldn't exec the above command.